# Cannot resolve getButton method after creating alertDialog

Tags: java, android

I've tried to solve this issue reading around on stackoverflow and also I've tried to understand better the use of `getButton` method reading directly from android studio website.
Below the description directly from developer.android.com (bold is mine) :

> public Button getButton (int whichButton)
>
> Gets one of the buttons used
>   in the dialog. Returns null if the specified button does not exist or
>   the dialog has not yet been fully created (for example, via
>   **Dialog.show()** or **Dialog.create()**).

**MapsActivity.java**

As you can see below I use `getButton` method after `Dialog.show()` but i get `error: cannot find symbol method getButton(int)`
. Could you tell me which is the problem? Thanks

...

```
case R.id.settings:

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.SettingDialogStyle);

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_alert_dialog, null);


                    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
                    final TextView txtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.intervalValue);

                    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            txtView.setText(String.valueOf(progress)+ " sec");


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


                    builder2.setView(v);
                    builder2.setTitle("Interval between updates");
                    builder2.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User clicked OK button
                        }
                    });
                    builder2.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });


                    builder2.show();

                    final Button positiveButton = builder2.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams positiveButtonLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
                    positiveButtonLL.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    positiveButton.setLayoutParams(positiveButtonLL);


                    return true;
```

...

**setting_alert_dialog.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intervalValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:max="60"
        android:progress="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:thumbTint="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: any feedback after the answers below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getButton()` is a member of the class `AlertDialog` not `AlertDialog.Builder`.  
if you change to:  
 `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(this, R.style.SettingDialogStyle);`  
then you have access to `alertDialog.getButton()`

Alternative, after this line:

```
      AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.SettingDialogStyle);
```

by this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder2.create();
```

you have the alert dialog that can access `getButton()`

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that `getButton()` is a method of `AlertDialog` class by taking a look at the AOSP project at

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java#L239

so, the correct code should be the following:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder2.show();
final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
```